# A fly on a cube's vertex

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

There is a fly on a cube's vertex. The fly is expected to walk over every side of the cube once and return to the starting vertex. Is that possible?

Comment: ... without visiting a side more than once or?

Comment: By "side" do you mean edge?

Comment: ... or using the fly's ability to fly? or walk across the faces? or burrow through the inside of the cube? Google for "Eulerian graph" and "Hamiltonian graph" for information about the kind of problem you probably had in mind.

Comment: Yes by side I mean edge! Thanks for the correction! And yes, without visiting the edge more than once.

Comment: Only by walking across the edges.

Comment: You are looking for an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each vertex, there are odd number of edges connected to it. Hence it is not possible, you need even degree to return to the starting vertex.

Further explanation:

The very first time you you leave the starting vertex. you used one edge connected to the starting edge.

The next time, you revisit the starting vertex, you used another edge.

If you use the third edge connected to it, you run out of edge to come back to the starting vertex.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but you cannot really "revisit" the starting vertex until you have walked over all the other edges. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If we are not allowed to revisit the starting edges until we have walked over all the other edges, then the number of edges connected to the starting vertex must be $2$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.